# Firebase: $scoping array of query of record children

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have an AngularJS app that creates to do lists and saves them onto Firebase ($FirebaseArray).  I would like to display a chart that shows a contrast between those item objects whose properties show `completed: true` and those objects whose properties show `completed: false`.  In order to do that, I have to create two different arrays for each kind of item.

I can manage to `console.log` the results of these arrays, but I am having difficulties displaying these arrays in the DOM via $scope, much less feeding them into the Angular-ChartJS scripts.

Here is what my Firebase looks like:

```
{
  "items": {
    "KUnjnUG90g4Ms_pkbC5": {
      text: "I need to do my hw",
      dueDate: 1477647527093,
      hoursToFinish: 1,
      minutesToFinish: 5,
      importance: "job depends on it",
      completed: true,
      pastDue: true,
      urgent: true,
      rank: 4089044218,
      created_at: 1477263177719
    },
   "KUq51IiPh4RgaC_v0Rg": {
      text: "asdf",
      dueDate: 1477647527093,
      hoursToFinish: 1
      minutesToFinish: 5
      importance: "pretty important"
      completed: false,
      pastDue: true
      urgent: true
      rank: 3792736666
      created_at: 1477302560019
    }
  }
}
```

A factory handles the `ref` for the controller in question:

```
listo.factory("ItemCrud", ["$firebaseArray",
  function($firebaseArray) {

    var ref = new Firebase("database");
    var items = $firebaseArray(ref);
    ...

    return {
      getAllItems: function() {
        return items;
      }
    }
    ...
  }
]);
```

Here is the controller with the query in question (`$scope.updateArrays`):

```
listo.controller('UserCtrl', ["$scope", "ItemCrud", "$rootScope", "$interval", "$log", "$http", "$locale", "$templateCache", '$timeout',
   function($scope, ItemCrud, $rootScope, $interval, $log, $http, $locale, $templateCache, $timeout) {

  $scope.items = ItemCrud.getAllItems();

  $scope.completeItems = [];
  $scope.incompleteItems = [];

  $scope.updateArrays = function() {
    var items = ItemCrud.getAllItems();
    items.$loaded().then(function(items) {

      items.$ref().orderByChild("q_completed").equalTo(true).on("value", function(snapshot) {
        console.log("updateArrays called");

        var completeItems = [];
        completeItems = Object.keys(snapshot.val());

        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          console.log("found", completeItems);
          return completeItems;
        } else {
          console.warn("completeItems was not found.");
          return [];
        }

      });

      items.$ref().orderByChild("q_completed").equalTo(false).on("value", function(snapshot) {

        var incompleteItems = [];
        incompleteItems = Object.keys(snapshot.val());

        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          console.log("found", incompleteItems);
          return incompleteItems;
        } else {
          console.warn("incompleteItems was not found.");
          return [];
        }

      });

      return {
        incompleteItems: incompleteItems,
        totalIncompleteItems: incompleteItems.length,
        completeItems: completeItems,
        totalCompleteItems: completeItems.length
      }

    });
  };

 }
]);
```

To ask my question simply: What coding would I have to undertake in order to display `$scope.updateArrays().totalIncompleteItems` and `$scope.updateArrays().totalCompleteItems` onto my DOM?

That is, how can I get the below to display:

```
<section ng-controller="UserCtrl" class="user">
    {{$scope.updateArrays().totalIncompleteItems}} and {{$scope.updateArrays().totalCompleteItems}}
</section>
```

As of now in my app these don't display.  However, the `console.log`s inside `$scope.updateArrays()` log the following onto my console:

```
updateArrays called
UserCtrl.js:495 found completeItems array ["-KUnjnUG90g4Ms_pkbC5", "-KUq51IiPh4RgaC_v0Rg", "-KUq6pXzElRP9JQC6AJB", "-KUq7WvMzH4FNaLdGL90"]
UserCtrl.js:510 found incompleteItems array ["-KVMv-hKRzk-WXv-KrOv", "-KVMv1nIC26elEBX7QA-", "-KVMv3qAtVNTW0j7sU8K", "-KVMv5smhYTeaDFGYmoh"]]
```

I would be very grateful if someone with deep knowledge of Firebase querying could post a plunker of the solution.

Comment: It is not wise to invoke a large asynchronous function inside an interpolation: `{{$scope.updateArrays().totalIncompleteItems}}` will invoke the `updateArrays` function multiple times every digest cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting keys instead of values.

Modify the following code

```
var completeItems = [];
completeItems = Object.keys(snapshot.val());

if (snapshot.exists()) {
  console.log("found", completeItems);
  return completeItems;
} else {
  console.warn("completeItems was not found.");
  return [];
}
```

into this.

```
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  completeItems.push(childSnapshot.val());
});

console.log("found", completeItems);
```

Do the same for incomplete items

Comment: Thank you for your response, Zura.  I actually wanted the keys.  The solution you propose still does not solve why the queried data does not persist in such a way so as to display in the DOM via $scope.

Comment: So the problem is to only display keys in the DOM?